# How to create a ssh key so that it can only use sshfs on a Synology NAS?

Tags: ssh, nas, sftp, sshfs, synology

I have an ssh key without a paraphrase that allows a user to log in to a remote server.

This key is used to mount a folder in the remote server using sshfs and backup the files in my laptop.

I would like this key to have sufficient privileges to the backup only. So, since sshfs uses sftp, I thought putting:

> command="path to sftp in the server"

in the server's authorized_keys file would work.

Now, when I log in via ssh, I get this:

> usage: sftp [-1246Cpqrv] [-B buffer_size] [-b batchfile] [-c cipher]
>
> ```
>    [-D sftp_server_path] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file] [-l limit]
>    [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-R num_requests] [-S program]
>    [-s subsystem | sftp_server] host
>
>    sftp [user@]host[:file ...]
>    sftp [user@]host[:dir[/]]
>    sftp -b batchfile [user@]host
> ```
>
> Connection to "my server's name" closed.

I take this to mean that this key can only use sftp, which is what I wanted.

However, when I use sshfs, I get the following:

> remote host has disconnected

The server is a Synology NAS DS212j with DSM 4.2 and there is no sftp-server program. The following is what the subsystem section looks like in the sshd_config file:

> # override default of no subsystems
>   #Subsystem      sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server
>   #Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp -f DAEMON -l VERBOSE -u 000
>
> Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp -f DAEMON -u 000
>   #Subsystem       sftp    /usr/syno/sbin/sftp-server -l DEBUG3

sshfs using a key without any restrictions on the commands works fine.

Please advise. Are there more commands I should include in the "command" variable in the authorized_keys file?

Thank you in advance for any help provided.

Comment: The output you show with the ssh login makes me think you have the path to the sftp in the command string, not the path to the sftp server.  The string should be something like command="/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server"

Comment: @Ciclamino yes, I actually put the path to sftp. I've edited my question to include more details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sshfs which command you must authorize but if you want add many command authorized for a specific key you can use a bash script to perform the authorization:

> command="/home/user/validate-rsync.sh" ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1yc

**/home/user/validate-rsync.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" in
*\&*)
echo "Rejected"
;;
*\;*)
echo "Rejected"
;;
rsync\ --server*)
$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
;;
*)
echo "Rejected"
;;
esac
```

make sure the script validate-rsync.sh is executable. I hope it can help you.